# Where is Android LCD backlight control code?

Tags: android

I'm trying to know how the LCD backlight is controlled in Android. I figured out that /sys/class/leds/lcd-backlight/brightness file is used.

However, I can't find core source code to control the backlight. Is it in Android kernel or specific device driver?

Please give me some advice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The liblights interface is used to control the backlight. When porting to a device you have to implement a specific version: http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/lights.html

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

The code is device specific. If you download a kernel from amlogic openlinux site here:

http://openlinux.amlogic.com/download/linux/GPL_code_release/2012-11-20/

The backlight driver can be found in this file: "m1-kernel-android/drivers/amlogic/display/vout/lcd_ttl/tm070.c". There are 4 functions you can refer to:

```
void power_on_backlight(void);
void power_off_backlight(void);
unsigned get_backlight_level(void);
void set_backlight_level(unsigned level);
```

That is one example. Under the "vout" directory there are drivers for many LCDs. Each of them has implementations for the above interface functions.

The code that calls those functions can be found under "arch/arm/mach-meson3/". Just search the strings of the above interface functions, you will see.

Comment: Link is broken.